# FQL Query returns empty array

Tags: php, facebook-fql

I recently included the facebook comments widget on my site, and now I would like to, on another page tell how many comments each post on my site has.  My code looks like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(MY_API_KEY,MY_SECRET_KEY);
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'query' => 'SELECT text FROM comment WHERE xid=3', 
    'method' => 'fql.query'));
print_r($result);
```

If I run that same FQL query on this page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/
it works, but when run on my site it returns an empty array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue. Anybody found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing front end documentation with back end implementation. The link you posted is more for implementation in javascript.

You should be creating and instance of Facebook like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=> MY_API_KEY, 'secret'=> MY_SECRET_KEY));
```

That may be your problem, you may not be getting and authenticated instance of Facebook. The constructor function only takes 1 parameter.